# iOS 8 alertview: willDismissWithButtonIndex VS didDismissWithButtonIndex

Tags: objective-c, ios7, cocos2d-iphone, uialertview, ios8

I have been encountering some crashes when running my app built for iOS 7.1 on an iOS 8 device.

after a small research I discovered that it is caused by an attempt to dismiss an already dismissed element with the following error :

"***Attempt to dismiss from view controller while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!***"

Needless to say it did not occur on previous migrations.
I traced back the crash to

```
(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

and applied instead

```
(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

**which seems to fix the crashes**.

I was using the willDismiss... delegate for notifying an attempt to exit the current stage and closing the stage soon afterwards.

**My question is** if there is a major difference between those two regarding my current usage and what might be the consequences by switching between these two?

I am using cocos2d v1.1.0-beta2b

Comment: Will and did, meaning: these two methods run before and after dismissing the view.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it seems like `Attempt to dismiss from view controller while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!` is clear. A call to `-dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` is being made during another present or dismiss.

Here is the documentation for `UIAlertViewDelegate`:

[`-alertView:willDismissWithButtonIndex:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIAlertViewDelegate/alertView:willDismissWithButtonIndex:)

> Sent to the delegate before an alert view is dismissed.

[`-alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIAlertViewDelegate/alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:)

> Sent to the delegate after an alert view is dismissed from the screen.

When using the `-alertView:willDismissWithButtonIndex:`, if you present or dismiss a view controller, then you risk stepping on the dismiss of the `UIAlertView`'s view controller which generates the error.

When using the `-alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:`, if you present or dismiss a view controller, then you not have this error: the `UIAlertView`'s view controller has already been dismissed.